# Comparing AST Nodes

Tags: rascal

For calculating duplication, I am parsing a java project into the AST.

But when trying to compare the AST nodes, Declaration attributes such as `src` are compared too, which leads to the comparison failing.

This change was introduced  < 1 year ago where Declaration annotations were removed.

To negate this I have to do the following:

```
myAst = visit(myAst) {
    case node n : {
        n.src = |unknown:///|;
    }
}
```

And then compare the nodes.

Is there any other way to make comparing nodes easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching ignores keyword parameters if they arent part of the pattern.

```
rascal>data  X = z(int y = 0);
ok
rascal>x1 = z(y=3);
X: z(y=3)
rascal>x2 = z(y=4);
X: z(y=4)
rascal>x1 == x2
bool: false
rascal>x1 := x2
bool: true
rascal>z() := x1
bool: true
rascal>z(y=5) := x1
bool: false
rascal>
```

So if you want to test for equality, use pattern matching. If you are putting them in a map or a set, you will indeed have to "unset" them. There is a rascal function that does this in the most efficient way possible. The function `unset` in `Node` does it for the current node, and the `unsetRec` function does it recursively using a similar visitor as in your code.